# MongoDB instances and oplog

Tags: mongodb

I would like to ask a couple of things about `MongoDB` and `replica sets`:

I have different meteor applications running on my private server; each one of them uses a different meteor database (and does not need to access other databases); right now only one `mongod` instance is running on the server, serving all applications; should I run different `mongod` instances (one for every application)?

I would like to create a `replica-set` with `oplog`; my question is: this is only useful for performance when there are a lot of requests (coming from many different clients) or will improve performance also in every single request? (The different members of the replica set will cooperate to find faster the documents requested by a single client?)

Comment: Setting up a replica set will not improve performance. It will provide redundancy for your data set and high availability. Depending on the read preference set by your application, it will always only perform a read against a single mongod instance.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifing this; If I have everything running on a single dedicated server, with a lot of unused resources (memory, CPU and disk), is there something I can do to improve performance of mongodb?

Comment: If your server is too big try to use virtualization, like VMWare, to make many small servers to better cover your needs. What actually is the performance issue you facing?

Comment: the apps running on the server (built with meteor.js) are not as fast as expected; in particular every app renders fast enough, but then takes too much time loading (few) documents from mongo; the server is not consuming resources, and so I'm trying to understand how to improve this performance; you can see the loading time in this page for example: http://paesidisandalmazzo.it/ita/beni-in-rete

Comment: Try running a .explain() on your queries. It may be that you need an index to support your reads. (See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/ for more on indexing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to create a replica-set with oplog

As per `MongoDB` Documentation sources from **MongoDB IN ACTION** The Replica sets rely on two basic mechanisms: an `oplog` and a `heartbeat`. The **oplog** enables the replication of data, and the **heartbeat** monitors health and triggers `failover`.

At the heart of `MongoDB’s` replication stands the `oplog`. The `oplog` is a `capped collection` that lives in a database called **local** on every replicating node and records all `changes to the data`. Every time a client writes to the `primary`, an entry with enough information to reproduce the write is automatically added to the primary’s `oplog`.Once the write is replicated to a given secondary, that secondary’s `oplog` also stores a record of the write. Each oplog entry is identified with a `BSON timestamp`, and all secondaries
use the `timestamp` to keep track of the latest entry they’ve applied.

Applications sometimes query secondary nodes for `read` scaling. If that’s happening, this kind of failure will cause read failures, So it’s important to design your application with `failover` in mind.

let’s look more closely at a real oplog and at the operations recorded in it.
First connect with the shell to the `primary node` and switch to the **local** `database`.

```
amj:PRIMARY> use local
switched to db local
```

The **local** database stores all the **replica set** metadata and the **oplog**. Naturally, this database isn’t replicated itself. Thus it lives up to its name; data in the local database is supposed to be unique to the local node and therefore shouldn’t be replicated.If you examine the local database, you’ll see a collection called `oplog.rs`, which is where every replica set stores its `oplog`. You’ll also see a few system collections. Here’s the complete output:

```
amj:PRIMARY> show collections
me
oplog.rs
replset.minvalid
slaves
startup_log
system.indexes
system.replset
```

`replset.minvalid` contains information for the initial sync of a given replica set member, and `system.replset` stores the replica set config document. Not all of your `mongod` servers will have the `replset.minvalid` collection. `me` and `slaves` are used to implement `write` concerns, and `system.indexes` is the standard index spec container.

> right now only one mongod instance is running on the server, serving
>   all applications; should I run different mongod instances (one for
>   every application)

I don't think so it's good idea to run different one `mongod` instance for one `application`.

For Your Further Ref [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) and [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)